# How to move the whole window when mouse is on the window's custom widget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qmouseevent

Let's say I have a custom widget and add it to the main window in qt.

[image]

As you can see, the red area is the custom widget. What I want to do is when the mouse is pressed in the red area and moved, the whole window will move as well.

I know how to simply implement `mousePressEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent`; but when dealing with a window with the custom widget, I do not know how to move the whole window when mouse is pressed on the custom widget.

Also I want to mention that I only want the window movable when mouse is pressed and moved in the red area, and when mouse is pressed and moved in the rest part of the main window area, nothing will happen.

This is what my `CustomWidget` class looks like:

```
CustomWidget::CustomWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(50, 50);
    setStyleSheet("QWidget { background: red; }");
}

void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter painter(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &painter, this);
}

void CustomWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    xCoord = event->x();
    yCoord = event->y();
}

void CustomWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    move(event->globalX() - xCoord, event->globalY() - yCoord);
}
```

In case you wonder why I want to do this, in my app, I hid the title bar and drew a custom title bar by myself. But the window is not movable, so I want to make the whole window movable when mouse is pressed and moved on the title bar. 
Hope I explained myself clearly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To move the window from any widget it is necessary to be able to access the window, and for this we use the method `window()` that returns the top level, it is not necessary to separate the coordinates `x()` and `y()`, the following code implements the solution:

**customwidget.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMWIDGET_H
#define CUSTOMWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class CustomWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CustomWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
private:
    QPoint startPos;
};

#endif // CUSTOMWIDGET_H
```

**customwidget.cpp**

```
#include "customwidget.h"

#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyleOption>

CustomWidget::CustomWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(50, 50);
    setStyleSheet("QWidget { background: red; }");
}

void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter painter(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &painter, this);
}

void CustomWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    startPos = event->pos();
    QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void CustomWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPoint delta = event->pos() - startPos;
    QWidget * w = window();
    if(w)
        w->move(w->pos() + delta);
    QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: It is *not* necessary to reimplement the `paintEvent`. Widgets draw their background by default. By the time your `paintEvent` is invoked, the background is already drawn, and it's red :) You also should declare the event handlers `override`, since you're writing in C++11.

Comment: @KubaOber Well, just copy the example and add what I needed :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on Windows, can use it:

```
#include "mywidget.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <QWindow>

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
}

MyWidget::~MyWidget()
{

}

void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton))
    {
        HWND hWnd = ::GetAncestor((HWND)(window()->windowHandle()->winId()), GA_ROOT);
        POINT pt;
        ::GetCursorPos(&pt);
        ::ReleaseCapture();
        ::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, POINTTOPOINTS(pt));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void QHexWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QLabel *child = static_cast<QLabel*>(childAt(event->pos()));
    if (child!=mTitleBar)        //mTitlebar is the QLabel on which we want to implement window drag
    {
        return;
    }
    isMousePressed = true;
    mStartPos = event->pos();
}

void QHexWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(isMousePressed)
    {
        QPoint deltaPos = event->pos() - mStartPos;
        this->move(this->pos()+deltaPos);
    }
}

void QHexWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QLabel *child = static_cast<QLabel*>(childAt(event->pos()));
    if (child!=mTitleBar)
    {
        return;
    }
    isMousePressed = false;
}
```

I have implemented the above in one of my github project https://github.com/VinuRajaKumar/AVR-HEX-Viewer where QLabel is used as TitleBar for the window.